# Save Mat object in OpenCV Java to Hbase table

Tags: opencv, hbase

Currently I'm using OpenCV Java to extract image features and store them to Hbase table. But I get a problem that image features of an image are in Mat or MatOfKeyPoint type in OpenCV while if we want to insert data to Hbase table then we have to use byte[].

```
......
featureDetector.detect(trainImages, trainKeypoints);
descriptorExtractor.compute(trainImages, trainKeypoints, trainDescriptors);
//Save to Hbase
Put put = new Put(key.getBytes());
put.add(family, keypoints, trainKeypoints);//???trainKeypoints is MatOfKeyPoint type
put.add(family, descriptors, trainDescriptors));//????trainDescriptors is Mat type
........
```

Anyone who know any good solutions about how to do it, please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `MatOfKeyPoint and Mat is serializable/deserializable to byte[]` then you can just do that.
 
To store MatOfKeyPoint and Mat, get their byte[] representation. Write those byte[] to HBase. 
To read data from HBase, read the byte[] from HBase and then build corresponding object from byte[].

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. I also think about it but unfortunately MatOfKeyPoint and Mat are not  serializable/deserializable object.